# Gradle build failed: "Your project path contains non-ASCII characters"

Tags: gradle, build, build-error

I tried to build my project after updating my unity to version 2019.1. Unfortunately, it says Gradle build failed. I can't build that as internal because it's not supported anymore.

[image: gradle build failed]

Answer (score 0):

Your project folder probably in the desktop or in a non-ASCI character folder. Just make a new folder in C:// and put your project in it then re-open the project and compile.